# Why async ajax request doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asynchronous

I'm new in javascript. I'm using this script to auth in my api:

```
function try_login() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://some.api/auth",
        dataType: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: {
            username: document.getElementById('username').value,
            password: document.getElementById('password').value
        },
        success:  function (data)
        {
            // alert(data.jwt_token);
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', data.jwt_token);
            // alert(window.location);
            window.location.replace("/index.html");
            //  alert(window.location);
            return false;
        }
       // success: successLogin,
    });
}
```

And this is my html (also I'm using bootstrap):

```
<form class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" required="" autofocus="">
    <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="">
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" id="login_btn" onclick="try_login()">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

I have two troubles.
Firstly, why if I'll change async on true or remove it (because default is async true in ajax), it will not been send a post request to api, it will only refresh a page.

Secondly, when I use an async false post request, it makes normaly request to api and receives normaly response. Saving token in sessionStorage works perfectly, but window.location.replace doesn't redirect on next page. I also trying many kinds of this, such as:

```
window.location = "/index.html"

window.location.href = "/index.html"
```

and also trying set non relative path "www.mysite.com/index.html".

The Chrome warning says that synchronous request deprecated, but my first trouble as you can see I don't know how to use async request. 
Also, it seems like a magic, but if I uncomment all my allerts in success function, firefox will redirect me to "index.html".

Please, help me!

Comment: Do you ever want to submit that form? Or is it purely there to be run via ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Firstly, why if I'll change async on true or remove it (because default is async true in ajax), it will not been send a post request to api, it will only refresh a page.

Because you're submitting a form, which involves tearing down the page and cancels any in-progress ajax requests.

> Secondly, when I use an async false post request, it makes normaly request to api and receives normaly response. Saving token in sessionStorage works perfectly, but window.location.replace doesn't redirect on next page.

Because you're submitting a form. The `return false` in your `success` callback has no effect whatsoever on the `submit` event of the form. If you want to prevent the form submission from within the `success` handler, hook the `try_login` up with jQuery (not `onclick` attributes), accept the event object, and use `preventDefault()` on it.

---

It looks to me like you never really want to submit the form, and instead just want to use it to trigger ajax. If that's the case, there's no need to make your ajax synchronous (and good reasons not to):

```
function try_login() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://some.api/auth",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            username: document.getElementById('username').value,
            password: document.getElementById('password').value
        },
        success: function(data) {
            window.sessionStorage.setItem('token', data.jwt_token);
            window.location.replace("/index.html");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Remove the `onclick` and hook it up like this:

```
$("any-css-selector-for-the-form").on("submit", try_login);
```

You might want to show something to indicate the request is in progress.

Comment: Thanks for answer!
I want to send credentials in input textbox to api via post request and receive the response, I don't know how to handle response without ajax.

I tryed your code, but I can't understand where can I hook it up. I trying this:
$("#form-signin").on("submit", try_login()) 

And when I went to site, try_login func are working in every refresh. 
Sorry if I asking stupid questions I'm newbie in javascript

Comment: Oh my God, I forgot that the "#" is id and character "." is for class! 
Now it's working awesome, thank you!!